Black Outline Around geom_point and Color Match Legend - ggplot
I know this is probably simple and straightforward yet all the different methods I have tried fail to keep the fill color. I would like to have the first geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph_situ) have a black outline around the points so they stand out on the figure. There is only 12 data points being plotted with that geom_point.
I would also like to have the legend for those geom_point shapes be the appropriate color as what is displayed on the figure. Right now they are shape and color coded to their sight name and it matches colors based on sight for the other geom_point call however on the legend they are black.
Code
annotation_ph_sonde <- data.frame(
   x = c("2023-05-20", "2023-05-20"),
   y = c(8.6,6.4),
   label = c("TMDL Numeric Target Upper Limit = 8.5", "TMDL Numeric Target Lower Limit = 6.5")
)

library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph_situ, aes(x = sample_date_time, y = result, color = station_name, shape = station_name,
                                           group = station_name), size = 3)+
  geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph, aes(x = sample_date_time, y = result, color = station_name,
                                      group = station_name), size = 0.8, alpha = 0.6) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(8.5, 6.5), linetype = "solid", color = "black", size = 0.7) +
    scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 1)
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
    scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 2)
  ) +
  ggtitle(paste0("May 2023 - pH")) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .01, color = "grey60"),
    legend.margin = margin(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.01, color="grey60" ),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    legend.title=element_blank()) +
  labs(y="pH") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(6, 9), breaks = seq(6, 9, by = 0.5),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  geom_text(data = annotation_ph_sonde, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)) +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(may_sonde_ph$date),
                     labels = unique(may_sonde_ph$date),
                     expand = c(0.04,0.04))


Sample Data
may_sonde_ph <- structure(list(station_name = c("TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", 
"TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", 
"TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", 
"TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", 
"TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", 
"TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2"), sample_date_time = c("2023-05-12 11:00:00", 
"2023-05-12 11:00:00", "2023-05-12 11:00:00", "2023-05-12 11:00:00", 
"2023-05-12 11:15:00", "2023-05-12 11:15:00", "2023-05-12 11:15:00", 
"2023-05-12 11:15:00", "2023-05-12 11:30:00", "2023-05-12 11:30:00", 
"2023-05-12 11:30:00", "2023-05-12 11:30:00", "2023-05-12 11:45:00", 
"2023-05-12 11:45:00", "2023-05-12 11:45:00", "2023-05-12 11:45:00", 
"2023-05-12 12:00:00", "2023-05-12 12:00:00", "2023-05-12 12:00:00", 
"2023-05-12 12:00:00", "2023-05-12 12:15:00", "2023-05-12 12:15:00", 
"2023-05-12 12:15:00", "2023-05-12 12:15:00", "2023-05-12 12:30:00", 
"2023-05-12 12:30:00", "2023-05-12 12:30:00", "2023-05-12 12:30:00", 
"2023-05-12 12:45:00", "2023-05-12 12:45:00"), parameter = c("pH", 
"pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", 
"pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", 
"pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH"), result = c(8.32, 8.24, 
8.39, 8.17, 8.32, 8.23, 8.37, 8.12, 8.32, 8.22, 8.35, 8.05, 8.32, 
8.21, 8.34, 8, 8.32, 8.19, 8.32, 7.97, 8.32, 8.17, 8.3, 7.94, 
8.32, 8.14, 8.29, 7.9, 8.32, 8.12), units = c("None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None"), comments = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), date = c("2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-12"), ym = c("2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")


may_sonde_ph_situ <- structure(list(program = c("Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", 
"Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", 
"Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", 
"Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", "Ventura River TMDL", 
"Ventura River TMDL"), station_name = c("TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R1", 
"TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R2", "TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R3", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R4", "TMDL-R4"), sample_date_time = c("2023-05-12 06:17:00", 
"2023-05-19 04:42:00", "2023-05-26 04:55:00", "2023-05-12 05:26:00", 
"2023-05-19 04:11:00", "2023-05-26 04:20:00", "2023-05-12 04:30:00", 
"2023-05-19 03:33:00", "2023-05-26 03:25:00", "2023-05-12 03:36:00", 
"2023-05-19 02:40:00", "2023-05-26 02:45:00"), parameter = c("pH", 
"pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH", "pH"
), result = c(8.29, 8.38, 8.35, 8.35, 8.41, 8.3, 8.3, 8.34, 8.26, 
8, 7.84, 7.79), units = c("None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None"), date = c("2023-05-12", 
"2023-05-19", "2023-05-26", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-19", "2023-05-26", 
"2023-05-12", "2023-05-19", "2023-05-26", "2023-05-12", "2023-05-19", 
"2023-05-26"), ym = c("2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", "2023-05", 
"2023-05", "2023-05")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


The problem you are running into is that you need to manually specify shapes that has a border using scale_shape_manual. From there you need to trick geom_point a bit to get the desired results.
UPDATE:
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite
 


ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph_situ, aes(x = sample_date_time, y = result, fill = station_name,
                                           shape = station_name,
                                           group = station_name), size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph_situ, aes(x = sample_date_time, y = result, 
                                           shape = station_name,
                                           group = station_name), size = 3,
                color  = 'black', alpha = 1) +
  geom_point(data = may_sonde_ph, aes(x = sample_date_time,
                                      y = result, color = station_name,
                                      group = station_name),
                 size = 0.8, alpha = 0.6) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(6, 9), breaks = seq(6, 9, by = 0.5),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(may_sonde_ph$date),
                   labels = unique(may_sonde_ph$date),
                   expand = c(0.04,0.04)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=21:25)  +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(8.5, 6.5), linetype = "solid", color = "black", linewidth = 0.7) +
  scale_color_viridis(
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 2)
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(title = "May 2023 - pH", y = "pH") +  
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = .01, color = "grey60"),
    legend.margin = margin(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size=.01, color="grey60" ),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    legend.title=element_blank())
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.


Created on 2024-05-10 with reprex v2.1.0

That looks better for the points but I would like the legend to stay the same with two rows. The first row being circles color coded and the second row being shape and points above and below the correct color.

yes but then is it possible to have the shapes on the legend be filled with thier matching color as well?

Ahh in this case I think I misunderstood what you were looking, my apologies! All you would need to do is delete the guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) bit and hopefully, that would get you what you are looking for?
